# Popover resigning first responder for touch events to view controller that called the popover

Tags: objective-c

I have a popover that should disappear when the user touches a UIImageView in it. Then I create another UIImageView that the user drags into the original ViewController. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the first responder. How do I make it so that the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded all are directly called to the original ViewController?

This is what I have so far:

initializing Popover:

```
PopoverCreateNewBoardViewController *content = [PopoverCreateNewBoardViewController new];
    content.delegate = self;
    showPiecesPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
    showPiecesPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(150.0, 500.0);
    showPiecesPopover.delegate = self;
```

Popover.m

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *objectTouched = [touches anyObject];
    if ([objectTouched.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        UIImageView *imageViewTouched = (UIImageView*)objectTouched.view;
        [delegate pieceSelectedType:imageViewTouched.tag color:piecesColor];
        [self resignFirstResponder];
        [delegate touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [delegate touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)pieceSelectedType:(NSInteger)pieceType color:(NSInteger)pieceColor
{
    selectedPieceImageView.image = [self imageOfPieceType:pieceType color:pieceColor];
    movingPiece = YES;
    [showPiecesPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (movingPiece) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        [selectedPieceImageView setCenter:touchPoint];
    }
}
```

Using this code, the touchesMoved stops being called after about a second after the popover starts being dismissed.

Comment: Did you set the popover view controllers delegate to your main view controller?

Comment: Original post updated.